# drive.changes.list and drive.revisions.list timestamps for a file being changed don't match. Is this a bug?

Tags: google-drive-api

The timestamps provided by drive.changes.list and drive sometimes do not match. They are close, but the timestamps are off by a few seconds.

We were trying to look at the changes API, and after that pick the revision that has the same timestamp as the one listed in revisions. We are doing this instead of picking the head revision because we do some processing in our app to indicate we've processed a changed file.

Example output demonstrating the issue is as below:

With the changes API I get back:

```
"modifiedDate": "2013-07-27T12:58:31.854Z",
```

With the revisions API

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AnwTzqT0JeG7dDFuQmtfbTNzWTd5eWNobllJa014aGc/revisions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is what I get back from drive.revisions.list

```
   "modifiedDate": "2013-07-27T12:58:29.152Z",
```

Is this a bug? It's preventing us from trying to make a changes call, and then trying to pick the version of the file corresponding to a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes.list() shows aggregated changes of overall Drive. It can't list changes of every files every single second thus can't be as accurate as file revision. This is not bug. Changes should be mere reference of what's going on on Drive. FYI, you might want to use [push notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/push). This monitors file revisions and tells you whenever changes are made to the file.